# Site Web Analytics Reports Date Range

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

I am trying to get web analytics for a specific site (not site collection). More specifically the "Top Visitors" report. However I am trying to get this report for a range of 1 year instead of the default 30 days.

I am aware I can change the date range to more than 30days in the central administration version of the report but I don't want to target an entire site collection only specific spweb sites within my site collection.

Does anyone know of a way to get this? Or if maybe there is a setting that I have to enable to get this information at this level?

Answer (score -1):

You can click on the Analyze Tab>More and then either select the 365 day option of custom date range.

Comment: As I stated above, I am fairly certain this is only available in the central administration version of the report that is not for a specific site but the site collection...